# Center align all dataframe headers except two that one of them must align left and the other right

Tags: python, pandas

The code below creates a table with the values of all columns centered and the column titles also centered. I align the values in the `local_team` column to the right and the values in the `visitor_team` column to the left:

```python
ef dfi_image(list_dict,name_file):
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_dict)
    df = df[['time','competition','local_team','score','visitor_team','channels']]

    df = df.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector='th', props=[('text-align', 'center'),('background-color', '#40466e'),('color', 'white')])])
    df.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'}).hide(axis='index')
    df.set_properties(subset=['local_team'], **{'text-align': 'right'}).hide(axis='index')
    df.set_properties(subset=['visitor_team'], **{'text-align': 'left'}).hide(axis='index')
    
    dfi.export(df, name_file + ".png")
dfi_image(games,'table_dfi.png')
```

[image]

But the title of `local_team` doesn't align to the right and neither the title of `visitor_team` aligns to the left and I need them with equal alignment to the values of these columns.

So i try:

```python
def dfi_image(list_dict,name_file):
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_dict)
    df = df[['time','competition','local_team','score','visitor_team','channels']]

    df = df.style.set_table_styles([
        dict(selector='th', props=[('text-align', 'center'), ('background-color', '#40466e'), ('color', 'white')]),
        dict(selector='th.col_heading.local_team', props=[('text-align', 'right')]),
        dict(selector='th.col_heading.visitor_team', props=[('text-align', 'left')])
    ])
    df.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'}).hide(axis='index')
    df.set_properties(subset=['local_team'], **{'text-align': 'right'}).hide(axis='index')
    df.set_properties(subset=['visitor_team'], **{'text-align': 'left'}).hide(axis='index')

    dfi.export(df, name_file + ".png")
dfi_image(games,'table_dfi.png')
```

[image]

how to proceed for the result is equal this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [Styler.set_table_styles](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html):

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [1000000000, 2000000000],
        "col2": [4000000000, 5000000000],
        "col3": [7000000000, 8000000000],
        "col4": [10000000000, 11000000000],
        "col5": [13000000000, 14000000000],
    }
)
```

To center align all column headers except `col2` (right align) and `col3` (left align):

```py
styles = (
    {
        key: [{"selector": "th", "props": [("text-align", "center")]}]
        for key in df.columns
        if key not in ["col2", "col3"]
    }
    | {"col2": [{"selector": "th", "props": [("text-align", "right")]}]}
    | {"col3": [{"selector": "th", "props": [("text-align", "left")]}]}
)

df.style.set_table_styles(styles)
```

Output in a Jupyter notebook cell:

[image]